# Solr data import - refreshing status gets different statuses

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am running a Solr cloud consisting of five servers.  I start a dataimport from the Solr Admin UI.  When I refresh the status I do not get a consistent result - one time I might get the status of the currently running import, another I might get "No information available (idle)", and another I might get the status of a previous attempt which succeeded/failed".  Am I correct in assuming that this is happening because the import is handled by a single server but the status request is going to all of the servers so 80% of the time the request will be answered by a server that is not running the import?

Is there a way that I can just get the status of the running import?  I tried sending the status request to the server that is running the import and I still get different messages each time I make the request.

Comment: You're correct in assuming that the DIH task only runs on a single server, but I can't give a good answer on why you're seeing varying responses. However, DIH has been removed from the main Solr core in Solr 9 (and moved into a separate project). Usually you'll see far better performance and flexibility with a custom indexer written in your language of choice and with an existing Solr library for that language (which will be able to use all nodes for processing the input as well).